# Checkbox on Datagrid with auto-generated columns, how to pass check-state to source without row change?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form with DataBound DataGrid on it. Bound to a list of objects. One of the objects property's is a boolean. So the grid shows it as a Checkbox.

When I click on the check box the tick appears or disappears but does not update the underlying data, until I change rows.

This is a bit counter intuitive, is there fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a bit of rummaging around in mdsn, quickview and immediate window:

```
dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange);
```

!